# How can I use bootstrap 3 modal to open self?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 3 for a project.

```
<div data-target="#bs_id" data-toggle="modal" class="carousel-content" id="bs_id">

<div> There is a lot of  content here </div>
<div> I like to show all of the content in a modal window </div>

</div>
```

What I want to do is to click the div with the id "bs_id" and display all its content in a modal window. I don't know how to reference itself so any help would be greatly appreciated, especially dynamic one ( using jQuery's .on ),

Thanks,

M@KM

Answer (score 0):

You have put id and data-ref in same tag it should refer the id to the div.
so make structrue like this it will work.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div data-target="#bs_id" data-toggle="modal" class="carousel-content" >
      <div class="content_wrapper modal fade" id="bs_id" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div> There is a lot of  content here </div>
        <div> I like to show all of the content in a modal window </div>
       </div>    
     </div>
```